# Trying to save data to Database by SugarORM

Tags: java, android, sugarorm

according to the instructions on the official website,  try to save Book into Database by SugarOrm.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnSave;
    EditText title;
    EditText title2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        title = findViewById(R.id.e1);
        title2 = findViewById(R.id.e2);
        btnSave = findViewById(R.id.b1);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String temporatyTitle = title.getText().toString();
                String temporaryEdition = title2.getText().toString();

                Book book = new Book(temporatyTitle, temporaryEdition);
                book.save();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

2class

```
public class Book extends SugarRecord<Book> {

    String title;
    String edition;

    public Book(){

    }

    public Book(String title, String edition){
        this.title = title;
        this.edition = edition;
    }

}
```

I got error

> no such table: BOOK

How to create this table ? I can't find this on the official website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have fully setup your manifest file as recommended in the documentation. try changing your db version number to an higher value